# is it possible to store method name in an array, and count how many times it has been called?

Tags: java, arrays, stack, callstack

I need to simulate a call stack. Now I've already implemented my stack, now I'm wondering if there's a way to store the method name in the array.

For instance, I have a recursion function that loops 5 times, so the stack will be:

```
recur() //fifth 
recur() //fourth
recur() //third
recur() //second
recur() //first
```

but is there anyway to store them into an array and display it out? I don't have to care about what it does inside the recursion function, I just want to display out the name of the stack and the sequence and how it works.

Comment: How generic does this need to be? Do you need to capture any method, or just this one?

Comment: @Mureinik what do you mean by capture any method? can you explain it more?

Comment: Are you just trying to count the number of time `recur` is called, or **any** method in the stack trace (e.g., methods calling `recur` or methods called by it)

Comment: @Mureinik jsut the number of times of recursion function is called will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the number of invocations without passing any new parameter to the `recur` method.

`recursiveMethodCount` filters the current stack trace and counts the ocurrences.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackTrace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recur();
    }

    public static void recur() {
        long recursionLevel = recursiveMethodCount("StackTrace", "recur");
        if (recursionLevel < 10) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Recursion level is %d, invoking recur() again.", recursionLevel));
            recur();
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.format("Recursion level is %d, no more invocations.", recursionLevel));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Recursion level is %d, returning.", recursionLevel));
    }

    public static long recursiveMethodCount(String declaringClass, String methodName) {
        return Arrays.stream(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())
                .filter(stackTraceElement -> stackTraceElement.getClassName().equals(declaringClass))
                .filter(stackTraceElement -> stackTraceElement.getMethodName().equals(methodName))
                .count();

    }
}
```

The output of this code is

```
Recursion level is 1, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 2, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 3, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 4, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 5, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 6, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 7, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 8, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 9, invoking recur() again.
Recursion level is 10, no more invocations.
Recursion level is 10, returning.
Recursion level is 9, returning.
Recursion level is 8, returning.
Recursion level is 7, returning.
Recursion level is 6, returning.
Recursion level is 5, returning.
Recursion level is 4, returning.
Recursion level is 3, returning.
Recursion level is 2, returning.
Recursion level is 1, returning.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you ask?

```
    List<String> listName=new ArrayList<String>();
        listName.add(recur());
        listName.add(recur());
        listName.add(recur());
        listName.add(recur());
        listName.add(recur());


        System.out.println(listName);
        System.out.println(listName.size());
```

In this example, recur() return a String;

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know how often a function was called the simplest way would be to use a counter and increment it on the start of the function:

```
static int recur_counter = 0;
???? recur() {
    recur_counter++;
    // And now do whatever you actually wanted to do.
}
```

And after you are done calling the function you can just print the result:

```
System.out.println("recur() was executed " + recur_counter + " times.");
```